QGIS scale-based callouts
Is it possible to have scale-based callouts?
I want to display callouts if I zoom out and the scale is larger than 8000.
I have tried rule-based labels and checked the scale range and set the minimum to 8000. I have also checked draw call outs in the same rule. But no labels at whichever scale are showing.

Please provide your exact label settings.

Aside from the provided answer, if your labels don't show, you might have done something different wrong when it comes to compiling your labels.

You may use data-driven override on the callout lines, based on the variable @map_scale.

